# Communicate between Web Api and the Dal layer to query on DbContext

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

Good time

I have three layers of UI, BLL, DAL.

I added a WEB API layer. I also have a class called PersonController, which I added to the WEB API project. The class is:

```
  public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<CommonPerson> GetAllPersons()
    {
         PersonRepository PersonRep = new PersonRepository();
        return PersonRep.SelectAll();   
    }
}
```

In the GetAllPersons action, the PersonRepository class is called and goes to DAL from DbContext on the database queries.
The problem with this is that it can not read in the DAL, which can be read connection string, and make a mistake.

How can I connect the web api with the dal layer?

Comment: I didn't understand this part: The problem with this is that it can not read in the DAL, which can be read connection string, and make a mistake. Please clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is:

> DbContext => Repository => Unit of Work => BLL => ApiController

Here is a good resource:
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/01/28/unit-of-work-repository-pattern-in-mvc5-and-web-api-2-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-ninject